# Which books teach numerical method for system of differential equations?

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Which books teach numerical method for system of differential equations?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://faculty.olin.edu/bstorey/Notes/DiffEq.pdf) (site about numerical methods for differential equations) seems to be a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but... learning the state-of-the-art would warrant reading the [two](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1) [volumes](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-05221-7) of *Solving Ordinary Differential Equations* by Hairer, Wanner (and Nørsett); one for nonstiff problems, and one for stiff problems. The bibliography should be able to point you to the other useful books, including [Bill Gear's classic](https://books.google.com/books?id=e9QQAQAAIAAJ).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by system of differential equations. I would recommend this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=uvpwKK7ZVwMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=fundamentals+of+engineering+numerical+analysis&source=bl&ots=LnG-pgD66w&sig=dj5VGdHzFlYStPoTarRzKNwSttQ&hl=en&ei=nq9iTcTMI5OosAOBv7HNCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false). It covers a good amount of numerical analysis for ODE's and PDE's. It has a good amount of problems and illustrations and is fairly rigorous.